# Specific Regular Expression for PHP String

Tags: php

**The strings are always different! I do NOT know `Rate the Code` will actually be.**

I'm looking for a specific regular expression for a PHP string that I'm trying to parse.

I have string that looks like this:

```
- :description: Rate the Code
  :long_description: ""
  - :description: Full Marks
    :long_description: ""
  - :description: No Marks
    :long_description: ""
- :description: Rate the Asthetics
  :long_description: This is a long description for Rate the Asthetics.
  - :description: Full Marks
    :long_description: ""
  - :description: No Marks
    :long_description: ""
```

with a line break after every line.

I would like parse out the word `Rate the Code`. This requires the regex to look for:

- The last colon
- Move two characters over
- Then get the text until the next line break "`\n`".

PHP:

```
if (strpos($explodearray[$i], 'description:') !== false) {
    echo $explodearray[$i]."\n";
}
```

Comment: If its always going to be the same word, why even parse the haystack?

Comment: It's not going to be.

Comment: Then please mention your requirement correctly; `I would like to get the word Rate the Code` is confusing

Comment: How does that not make sense to you? I need to get the word `Rate the Code` from the  string.

Comment: Yes it will be. Only the text after the key will change.

Comment: I'm modyfing my answer given your full exemple. Taking only after description and not longdescription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer with a regex with your description:

`/^.*:\s(.*)$/gm`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gL0lE7/2)
Explanation:
capture text after `:` until the end of line.

It takes the values for description and longdescription.

Php demo [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81f82605a2f618d01056ef2ea1a4d33ebcf91530)

the PREG_MATCH_OFFSET is not needed, matches[1] will contain an array of matched text.

Comment: Actually, I do need long description  as well, so your reg ex works perfectly.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work? `preg_match_all("/^.*:\s(.*)$/mg", $explodearray[$i], $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3); print_r($matches);` Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: What does $explodearray[$i] contain ?

Comment: It contains what is posted in my OP. That block of text.

Comment: Hum, seems the g is not needed, replaced by preg_match or preg_match_all, in your case preg_match should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at RegEx, so there might be a shorter way to write this, but if I understand the question correctly, you are wanting to convert that flat file format to an array?

Where $str is your flat structure string:

```
$re = "/\\s*\\-?\\s*:([a-zA-Z0-9\\_]*):\\s*(.*)\\n?/"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Would return:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [3-14]  `description`
2.  [16-29] `Rate the Code`
MATCH 2
1.  [33-49] `long_description`
2.  [51-53] `""`
MATCH 3
1.  [59-70] `description`
2.  [72-82] `Full Marks`
MATCH 4
1.  [88-104]    `long_description`
2.  [106-108]   `""`
MATCH 5
1.  [114-125]   `description`
2.  [127-135]   `No Marks`
MATCH 6
1.  [141-157]   `long_description`
2.  [159-161]   `""`
MATCH 7
1.  [165-176]   `description`
2.  [178-196]   `Rate the Asthetics`
MATCH 8
1.  [200-216]   `long_description`
2.  [218-268]   `This is a long description for Rate the Asthetics.`
MATCH 9
1.  [274-285]   `description`
2.  [287-297]   `Full Marks`
MATCH 10
1.  [303-319]   `long_description`
2.  [321-323]   `""`
MATCH 11
1.  [329-340]   `description`
2.  [342-350]   `No Marks`
MATCH 12
1.  [356-372]   `long_description`
2.  [374-376]   `""`
```

Answer (score -1):

Without a better explanation of your requirements, what about:

```
if($myString=='- :description: Rate the Code' . "\n"){
  $myResult='Rate the Code';
}
```

After reading your extra explanation, why not just use:

```
$myString=<<<EOS
- :description: Rate the Code
  :long_description: ""
  - :description: Full Marks
    :long_description: ""
  - :description: No Marks
    :long_description: ""
- :description: Rate the Asthetics
  :long_description: This is a long description for Rate the Asthetics.
  - :description: Full Marks
    :long_description: ""
  - :description: No Marks
    :long_description: ""
EOS;

preg_match('/(:description:(.*))/', $myString, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: The strings are always different.... *sigh* I don't know what "Rate the Code" will be.